# Webots recorded movie default saved location

Tags: webots

I used Webots with Python external controller and want to try to record my simulation. By looking at the console output of webots, I can see that recording movie success. I used Python with ROS to create controller for DarwinOP3, Normally all files will be saved into $ROS_HOME path. But I am unable to find where the movie file is. I try with simple Python script to record, but I am also unable to find the file.

```sh
INFO: Creating video...
Recording at 31.25 FPS, 2531250 bit/s.
Video encoding stage 1... (please wait)
Video encoding stage 2... (please wait)
INFO: Video creation finished.
```

Comment: Are you using the ROS `/supervisor/movie_start_recording` service or the Webots Python API (i.e. the `Supervisor.movieStartRecording`) function?

Comment: No, I created my own interface to ROS. I used supervisor node and record with
```python
self.supervisor.movieStartRecording("video_robot", 640, 480, 1337, 100, 1, True)
```

Comment: Can you try to replace the "video_robot" filename by an absolute path and adding the ".mp4" extension (e.g. "/home/username/video_robot.mp4")?